# Snap multiple vertices simultaneously

Tags: modeling, snapping

I know how to snap vertices to the face of a mesh one by one. Is there any way to snap multiple vertices to the closest mesh all at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the settings I use for retopology with snapping. [image](Note the options on the right of Closest)

If you make an extrusion, and the vertices don't snap to the mesh underneath, just press g with the vertices selected and they should snap.